# Decoding smime.p7m file in PowerShell fails with error message "ASN1 bad tag value met."

Tags: powershell, decode, exchangewebservices, asn.1, smime

I have a PowerShell script which saves email attachments to local disk. To get the emails the EWS Managed API (Download [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42951)) is used.
Emails that contain attachments get loaded from a mailbox and then the attachments get stored to local disk.

If it's an unsigned email, the script is working fine and the attachment is getting saved properly. But if it's a S/MIME signed mail I am getting the following error:

```
Exception calling "Decode" with "1" argument(s): "ASN1 bad tag value met.
"
At C:\Get-Attachments.ps1:47 char:2
+     $envelopObject.Decode($data);
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CryptographicException
```

My implementation is based on the code of [this blog post](https://maheshkumar.wordpress.com/2014/04/15/how-to-use-ews-api-for-reading-smime-email-message/).
I am loading the attachment into a stream and from there I am getting the content with `.GetBuffer()`. Then I am using an `EnvelopedCms` object to decode the content (that is where I am getting the error).

---

Below you can see my PowerShell script that is trying to decode the signed email. If the `$envelopObject.Decode($data);` inside `Decode-ToFile` function gets called, I am receiving the error shown above.

```
function Decode-ToFile([byte[]] $data)
{
    [byte[]] $resultObject = $null;
    
    [System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.EnvelopedCms]$envelopObject = [System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.EnvelopedCms]::new();
    $envelopObject.Decode($data);
    $resultObject = $envelopObject.ContentInfo.Content
    return $resultObject
}

function Save-Attachment
(
    [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FileAttachment] $attachment
)
{
    $attachmentName = $attachment.Name;
    
    if($attachmentName -eq "smime.p7m")
    {
        [System.IO.MemoryStream]$stream = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new();
        $attachment.Load($stream);
        [System.IO.StreamReader]$streamReader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($stream);
        $stream.Seek(0, [System.IO.SeekOrigin]::Begin);
        [byte[]] $data = $stream.GetBuffer();
        
        $decodedData = Decode-ToFile($data);
    }

    # Saving Attachment
    …
    …
}
```

I am trying to get the attachments of a S/MIME signed email to save them.

If there is an easier approach to do so, you are pleased to give me a hint.

If you need more information just hit me up and I will try to give you the needed information.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question, and found the MimeKit dotnet framework (http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Introduction.htm) and got it working like this (since I'm dutch-speaking, the remarks/variable names/log statements are dutch but I'm sure you can still figure out what's going on. If not, do get in touch):

1. Get the framework:

```
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
    Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet
    Register-PackageSource -name NuGet -Location https://www.nuget.org/api/v2 -ProviderName NuGet -Trusted
    Install-Package -SkipDependencies -Name MimeKit -ProviderName NuGet
    Install-Package -Name System.Buffers -ProviderName NuGet
```

2. Use the dll's in your ps code:

```
    $MimeKitDllPath = "C:\Program Files\PackageManagement\NuGet\Packages\MimeKit.2.11.0\lib\net46\MimeKit.dll"
    $SystemBuffersDllPath = "C:\Program Files\PackageManagement\NuGet\Packages\System.Buffers.4.5.1\lib\net461\System.Buffers.dll"
    Function LoadDll ($dll) {
        [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($dll)
    }
    
    LoadDll($MimeKitDllPath)  
    LoadDll($SystemBuffersDllPath)
```

3. Use the framework to decode the mime message: A signed mail is delivered from EWS as one big attachment. But inside the attachment, there are the parts that make up the mail body + all the attachments, so it's sort of like a zip file that needs decompressing the seperate files inside it.
   I do this via a seperate function that saves one attachment to disk, but is able to detect if it's this special attachment and then decode/unzip all attachments that are inside the **smime.p7m** file. This is the function that does that:

```
Function AttachmentNaarDisk($attach) {  
    $filebasename = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($attach.Name.ToString())
    $fileextension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($attach.Name.ToString())
    $LocalAttachmentFile = "$($TempDownloadDirectory)\$($filebasename)-$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMMddTHHmmss')$($fileextension)"
    $LocalAttachmentFile = $LocalAttachmentFile.Replace('[','').Replace(']','') # De [] wildcard tekens moeten eruit...vervangen door backtick prefix helpt wel voor invoke-webrequest MAAR de RestAPI kan er ook niet mee overweg, dus weg ermee
    Log "  Bijlage downloaden en wegschrijven naar $($LocalAttachmentFile)"
    $fiFile = new-object System.IO.FileStream($LocalAttachmentFile, [System.IO.FileMode]::Create)
    $fiFile.Write($attach.Content, 0, $attach.Content.Length)
    $fiFile.Close()

    # Check of het een signed message is
    if ($attach.ContentType -eq $MailboxBijlageSigned) {
        Log "  Bijlage is signed message - decoderen"
        $Bijlages = @()
        ## Hier dan de verwerking proberen te doen via MimeKit
        $message = [MimeKit.MimeMessage]::Load($LocalAttachmentFile)
        # Iterate over de onderdelen, haal de bijlages eruit
        $iter = [MimeKit.MimeIterator]::new($message)
        while ($iter.MoveNext()) {
            $part = $iter.Current
            Log "  Dit deel ContentType=$($part.ContentType.MimeType)"
            if ($null -ne $part -and $MailboxBijlageFilter -contains $part.ContentType.MimeType -and $part.ContentType.MimeType -ne $MailboxBijlageSigned -and $null -ne $part.FileName) {
                Log "  --> Goede bijlage gevonden..."
                Log "  Bijlage #$($BijlageTeller) type: $($part.ContentType.MimeType) - Grootte: $($part.Content.Stream.Length)  Naam: $($part.FileName)"
                $filebasename = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($part.FileName.ToString())
                $fileextension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($part.FileName.ToString())
                $LocalAttachmentFileIter = "$($TempDownloadDirectory)\$($filebasename)-$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMMddTHHmmss')$($fileextension)"
                Log "  Bijlage downloaden en wegschrijven naar $($LocalAttachmentFileIter)"
                $stream = [System.IO.File]::Create($LocalAttachmentFileIter)
                $part.Content.DecodeTo($stream)
                $stream.Close()
                $Bijlages += @{Name=$part.FileName; FileName=$LocalAttachmentFileIter}
            } else {
                Log "  --> Bijlage heeft niet gewenste content-type, overslaan!"
            }
        }
        Log "  Bijlage is signed message - decoderen klaar, verwijderen signed attachmentfile"
        Remove-Item -Path $LocalAttachmentFile
    } else {
        $Bijlages = @{Name=$attach.name.ToString(); FileName=$LocalAttachmentFile}
    }
    return $Bijlages
}
```

It filters out only attachments that I'm interested in, which are in an array called `$MailboxBijlageFilter` and looks like this:

```
$MailboxBijlageFilter = @(
    'application/xml',
    'text/xml',
    'application/pdf',
    'image/png',
    'image/jpeg',
    'image/tiff',
    'application/octet-stream',
    'multipart/signed'
)
```

Also, the `$MailboxBijlageSigned` variable contains just this:

```
$MailboxBijlageSigned = 'multipart/signed'
```

4. And finally, this is the code to iterate over attachments per mail:

```
    $BijlageTeller = 0
    $Bijlages = @()
    foreach ($attach in $MailItem.Attachments) {
        try {
            $BijlageTeller++
            $attach.Load()
            Log "  Bijlage #$($BijlageTeller) type: $($attach.ContentType) - Grootte: $($attach.Size)  Naam: $($attach.Name.ToString())"
            if ( $MailboxBijlageFilter -contains $attach.ContentType ) {   ## Alleen maar de gewenste bijlages doorsturen, de rest gewoon skippen
                $Bijlages += AttachmentNaarDisk($attach)
            } else { ## Ongewenste bijlages gewoon overslaan
                Log "  --> Bijlage heeft niet gewenste content-type, overslaan!"
            }
        } catch {
            Log "  Bijlage #$($BijlageTeller) probleem tijdens verwerking:  Message=$($_.Exception.Message);ItemName=$($_.Exception.ItemName)"
        }
    }
```